# JavaFX: KeyCode: Game A Key

Tags: javafx, keycode

I've browsed the docs, without any answers. What are the Game A Key... Game D Key in JavaFX? I'm assuming it's a reference to Gamepads, but I have no idea how it works or is configured. Any knowledge in this matter would be enlightening.

So: How do I use the Game (A, B, C, or D) Key in JavaFX for KeyCode input and what results should I expect?

Comment: Are you referring to the keyboard keys `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` ?

Comment: So you mean a w s d? A moves left D to right W up and S down?

Comment: No, not AWSD, those are normal KeyCodes. Please refer to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html   It is Game_A. Sorry for not being specific with the underscore.

Comment: These are used in J2ME and are general purpose key codes for "A Game Action" etc. I haven't seen any use of them in JavaFX so far, neither does the JavaFX code itself have any reference to it. The constant is defined in a "Mobile and Embedded Specific Key Codes" section of the KeyCode class.

Comment: Thank you, Roland. That answered my question.